# angular2 toaster - No Toaster Containers have been initialized to receive toasts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular2-toaster

i am using [angular2-toaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster) in my angular app

it is very simple,

you define toaster container in  the template of  component

```
<toaster-container></toaster-container>
```

and you use toasterService of type `ToasterService` to pop op toaster

```
  this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Args Title', 'Args Body');
```

but there is a problem with this approach, I would not  like  to define a container in 
every component I intend to pop a toaster,
 I would like to define it once in root component. where application bootstrap 
but when I do so, I get the error

```
 No Toaster Containers have been initialized to receive toasts.
```

any solution?

Comment: You probably have to provide the `ToasterService` in your root component, too! But not in all the sub components! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put `<toaster-container></toaster-container>` in the root component view.
Then inject the ToasterService in each of other components. You will still be able to do:

```
  this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Args Title', 'Args Body');
```

And don't forget to provide ToastService at module level.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/PfOLJa4Qh304cJHvIxOa?p=preview)

Comment: There is now a 5.0.0 release that enables toaster container inclusion outside of the root, as well as multiple containers while guaranteeing a singleton of the `ToasterService`.  This corrects the behavior seen by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the import path wasn't correct.
I faced this issue while I was upgrading the angular version from 6 to 10 and
I updated the `angular2-toaster` from 7.0.0 to 8.0.0

Changed it **from**,

```
import {ToasterConfig, ToasterService} from "angular2-toaster/angular2-toaster"; // Wrong
```

**to**,

```
import {ToasterConfig, ToasterService} from "angular2-toaster"; // Correct
```

Hope it helps someone who's seeking!